# Parquet Data Loading in Hive Slows Dramatically as Table Size Increases

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet

Story is that I've been attempting to convert the columns of a very large Hive table (~8TB) that is flat formatted and contains ~20K partitions into parquet so that I can start to utilize the vastly more efficient duo of parquet and PrestoDB for queries. In order to preserve the partitions of the original table, I'm loading the data one partition at a time using an HQL script, and I've parallelized the processes in a manner such that 10 load processes are run concurrently.

I'm running Hive 2.1.0 on a machine with 8GB of free RAM and 4 Intel Xeons @ 2.5 GHz.

Loading one partition (the size of the partitions vary, but they're ~500MB in the flat Hive table) takes roughly 190 seconds when the parquet table is empty, but as more and more of the queries run in parallel, the runtime increases dramatically!
[image: Graph of nastiness]

As you can see, the first batch of 9 run in about the same time, and then the runtime actually decreases, but everything starts slowing down significantly around 18.

I know that there are a truly vast number of ways that this could be going wrong, but my initial suspicion was that it was an issue with the parquet writing. So, I tried investigating potential bottlenecks there and found an interesting email exchange [here](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201507.mbox/%3C55B4A163.8010404@gmail.com%3E) about summary files in Spark, but apparently Hive doesn't even use them. I then considered the possibility that it was perhaps a memory issue, so I bumped up the HADOOP_HEAPSIZE parameter in hive-env.sh to 5GB - nothing changed.

I'm on my last leg and want to know if anyone has ever experienced a similar situation. If so, it would be greatly appreciated if you could share what the main culprit was and how you resolved everything.

Thanks!

EDIT: Someone wanted me to share my code and logs, so here is the most pertinent stuff.

I have a shell script that spits out a text file called tasks.txt that has a list of parameterized hive commands to run for each partition load. That text file looks like this:

```
hive -f insert.hql -hiveconf ATTRIBUTE=alpha -hiveconf MONTH=01 -hiveconf DAY=01
hive -f insert.hql -hiveconf ATTRIBUTE=beta -hiveconf MONTH=01 -hiveconf DAY=01
hive -f insert.hql -hiveconf ATTRIBUTE=gamma -hiveconf MONTH=01 -hiveconf DAY=01
hive -f insert.hql -hiveconf ATTRIBUTE=alpha -hiveconf MONTH=01 -hiveconf DAY=02
hive -f insert.hql -hiveconf ATTRIBUTE=beta -hiveconf MONTH=01 -hiveconf DAY=02
hive -f insert.hql -hiveconf ATTRIBUTE=gamma -hiveconf MONTH=01 -hiveconf DAY=02
.
.
.
```

This is the insert.hql script that loads and partitions the parquet

```
INSERT INTO TABLE foo_bar_pq 
 PARTITION (year=2017, month=${hiveconf:MONTH}, day=${hiveconf:DAY}, attribute='${hiveconf:ATTRIBUTE}') 
 SELECT 
   a,
   b,
   c,
   d,
   e
 FROM foo_bar_flat 
   WHERE year=2017 
   AND month=${hiveconf:MONTH} 
   AND day=${hiveconf:DAY} 
   AND attribute='${hiveconf:ATTRIBUTE}';
```

I parallelize this process and ensure it doesn't stop running by running a nohup bash runner.sh. runner.sh is below.

```
#!/bin/sh
cat tasks.txt | xargs -n 1 -I CMD -P 10 bash -c CMD
```

As far as logs go, they contain sensitive information and it isn't feasible for me to obfuscate the 500+ lines for even a single load query. I stared at them for a good amount of time and gleaned only that the maps took up ~90% of the query execution time and also took an increasingly long amount of time to run.

For example:

```
2017-06-27T19:54:14,524 INFO  [c6a35f57-aacf-4c23-bf37-f22095f02855 main([])]: client.TezClient (TezClient.java:submitDAGSession(522)) - Submitting dag to TezSession, sessionName=HIVE-c6a352017-06-27T19:54:16,518 INFO  [5e8d02e1-0880-45ee-953f-b31520c58a1d main([])]: SessionState (SessionState.java:printInfo(1054)) - Map 1: 0(+1)/1
2017-06-27T19:54:19,547 INFO  [5e8d02e1-0880-45ee-953f-b31520c58a1d main([])]: SessionState (SessionState.java:printInfo(1054)) - Map 1: 0(+1)/1
2017-06-27T19:54:22,565 INFO  [5e8d02e1-0880-45ee-953f-b31520c58a1d main([])]: SessionState (SessionState.java:printInfo(1054)) - Map 1: 0(+1)/1
.
.
.
2017-06-27T20:00:09,526 INFO  [5e8d02e1-0880-45ee-953f-b31520c58a1d main([])]: SessionState (SessionState.java:printInfo(1054)) - Map 1: 0(+1)/1
2017-06-27T20:00:12,539 INFO  [5e8d02e1-0880-45ee-953f-b31520c58a1d main([])]: SessionState (SessionState.java:printInfo(1054)) - Map 1: 0(+1)/1
2017-06-27T20:00:14,647 INFO  [5e8d02e1-0880-45ee-953f-b31520c58a1d main([])]: SessionState (SessionState.java:printInfo(1054)) - Map 1: 1/1
```

Comment: Share your code and your logs

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Done!